# Google Chrome - has popstate trigggering on initial page load changed in v34?

Tags: google-chrome, popstate

In version 34 of Chrome (Mac) has pop-state behavior changed on page load? A site that was working, now no-longer does. Preliminary analysis shows that the popstate event is now not firing on page-load - is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it has.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040

Unfortunately for me that means I now have to implement a fix given that Safari and Chrome now have different behavior.

Comment: Please note that this change has broken History.js, I've reported it to this History.JS team at https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/389

Comment: @cameron but this discussion was from 2010. I'm confused!